# Civicase add timeline but activities not shown

Tags: civicase

Version:civicrm-5.33.1-wordpress

I tried to create a timeline hoping then when i add it, it will be shown in the activities tab. But apparently this is not working. Is there any setting i missed out?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like another casualty from the button UI changes. Have added https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2292. Can you try this small patch? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19356/files

The way that dropdown works is a bit weird - changing the value clicks a hidden button, and the way buttons submit their name to the form has changed, so it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: This patch worked for me – @Demerit thanks for your fast help!

Comment: Thanks this patch works for me too!!